# Can not use git credential manager on Ubuntu

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-credential-manager

I have some repositories on Bitbucket that I can clone them using the git command line (HTTPS) it saves my password in Git Credential Manager and I do not need to enter it every time I am to pull or push to the repository.

Now I want to do the same thing in Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed Git Credential Manager and I am trying to clone one of my repositories.

I tried to use this command to configure the GCM:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
warning: credential.helper has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
```

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Then I am trying to clone a repository from bit bucket:

```
git clone https://<user_name>@bitbucket.org/<workspace>/<repo_name>.git
Cloning into '<repor_name>'...
fatal: Password store has not been initialized at '/home/user/.password-store'; run `pass init <gpg-id>` to initialize the store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
Password for 'https://<my user name>@bitbucket.org': 
fatal: Password store has not been initialized at '/home/user/.password-store'; run `pass init <gpg-id>` to initialize the store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.
remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit:
remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cloud/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/<workspace>/<repo_name>.git/'
```

First of all, why do I need to set up a password store?

Second, why I can not clone my repository at all? I am using the password that I use to log in to the bitbucket website. I am using the same password when cloning on windows and it is working properly.

third, how can I fix them so that when I am cloning my repositories, the oAuth method is used for my login and the results save on the system so I do not need to provide it every time that I want to do anything with git?